# Making a reusable Widget to use it multiple times

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a 'reusable body' Widget this way:

Under lib/widgets/body.dart is as follows:

```
//FLutter
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  
  Widget ofWelcome = const SizedBox();
  Widget ofUser = const SizedBox();
  Widget ofSearchField = const SizedBox();
  Widget ofContent = const SizedBox();

  Body({
    @required this.ofWelcome,
    @required this.ofContent,
    this.ofSearchField,
    this.ofUser
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Constant instance of the size of the device.
    final Size _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SizedBox(
      width: _size.width,
      height: _size.height,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () => Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              //Header
              ofWelcome,
              ofUser,
              ofSearchField,
              //Content
              ofContent,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm first calling my widget Body in a file lib/screens/home/home_screen.dart as the body of a Scaffold passing *ofWelcome*, *ofUser*, *ofSearchField* and *ofContent* widgets respectively to fill the widget's list inside the column of my Body and everything works. Then I'm reusing the same Body Widget as the body of another Scaffold and passing different *ofWelcome*, *ofUser*, *ofSearchField* and *ofContent*, but i'm getting an error of Null at the first parameter passed:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Body(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]):
Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 2


The relevant error-causing widget was
Body
lib/…/classroom_view/classroom_view.dart:32
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      new MultiChildRenderObjectWidget.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1899
#1      new MultiChildRenderObjectWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1905
#2      new Flex
package:flutter/…/widgets/basic.dart:3914
#3      new Column
package:flutter/…/widgets/basic.dart:4483
#4      Body.build
package:listado/widgets/body.dart:29
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

It is not null because *ofWelcome* is a SizedBox inside lib/widgets/header.dart:

```
class OfWelcome extends StatelessWidget {
  final String salute;
  final Size size;

  const OfWelcome({
    Key key,
    @required this.salute,
    @required this.size,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: size.height * 0.1,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              child: Text.rich(
                TextSpan(
                    text: salute,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: size.height * 0.1 - 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's how I first call Body in Home Screen and it works:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: new Body(
            ofWelcome: OfWelcome(salute: 'Bienvenido,', size: _size),
            ofUser: ofUser(auth, _size),
            ofSearchField: ofSearchField(_size),
            ofContent: ofContent(auth, _size)
          ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigator(
          size: _size,
          auth: widget.auth,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the Body called on another Scaffold where the error is thrown:

```
class _ClassroomViewState extends State<ClassroomView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: new Body(
        ofWelcome: OfWelcome(salute: widget.classroom, size: _size),
        ofContent: const SizedBox(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigator(size: _size, auth: widget.auth,),
    );
  }
}
```

What could be the problem?
Or,
If I'm using it wrong, how's the right way to write reusable widgets?

Comment: @RashidIqbal Already added lib/screens/home/home_screen.dart code, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> found at index 2

Since Dart is 0-indexed, "index 2" represents the third element on your list:

```
            [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ), // First
              ofWelcome, //Second
              ofUser, // Third
              ofSearchField,
              //Content
              ofContent,
            ]
```

So what contains the null value is the `ofUser` Widget.

Columns may not contain null widgets.

Since you did not mark some of the parameters as `@required` I presume you want to use the `Body` widget without passing them every time. In this case, you need to come up with a replacement for them or to check for null values before creating the column.

This can be done in various ways, here's a suggestion using [collection if](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators):

```
             [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ), // First
              ofWelcome, //Second
              if (ofUser != null) ofUser, // Third
              if (ofSearchField != null) ofSearchField,
              //Content
              ofContent,
            ]
```

You can use an empty container as a replacement aswell, using [null aware operators](https://dart.dev/null-safety#using-variables-and-expressions):

```
[
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ), // First
              ofWelcome, //Second
              ofUser ?? Container(), // Third
              ofSearchField ?? Container(),
              //Content
              ofContent,
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks! it solved the problem. I was trying to fix the null by declaring every Widget of... = const SizedBox(). I thought that would initialize them as SizedBox's even when they weren't passed, but that wasn't working, I don't really understand why